# How do you add typings to an installed Python module?

Tags: python

I installed a Python module that does not come with typings. Now I get a bunch of linter errors. I want to define my own `.pyi` file to ley Python know what exists in the module.

Here is my code:

```py
from RPi import GPIO

BUTTON_1 = 23
GPIO.setup(BUTTON_1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


def button_callback(pin):
    if pin == BUTTON_1:
        print("button 1 clicked")


GPIO.add_event_detect(BUTTON_1, GPIO.FALLING, callback=button_callback, bouncetime=100)
```

Here is a typings file that I created:

```py
from typing import Callable

def setup(pin: int, mode: int, pull_up_down: int) -> None: ...
def add_event_detect(
    pin: int, edge: int, callback: Callable, bouncetime: int
) -> None: ...

PUD_UP = 22
IN = 1
FALLING = 32
```

What do I need to do to get Python to know that this typings file belongs to this module?

I tried using these folder structures, with no luck:

```
test
|-- gpio
|   |-- __init__.pyi
|
|-- test.py
```

```
test
|-- gpio.pyi
|-- test.py
```

```
test
|-- RPi
|   |-- GPIO
|       |-- __init__.pyi
|
|-- test.py
```

Comment: does this help? https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs.html#creating-a-stub

Comment: I don't know where the module is installed because I installed it with pip, so I'm not sure where I can put the `.pyi` file. Plus, I don't really want to go modifying the installation manually. And in the case of using the `MYPYPATH` environment variable, I don't want a global env variable pointing at this one particular project. Any solutions to these problems? And I obviously don't want a global `~/stubs` folder either

Comment: all reasonable expectations. one option is to create a 'stub-only' package. see https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/#stub-only-packages and the bottom of https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installed_packages.html. that will provide type information without modifying the original package.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, but I'm finding these articles very tough to understand. I don't understand the difference between `foopkg-stubs` and `types-foopkg`. I've never heard of `distutils` before and I'm also not sure what the name of the package is in this case because it's `from x import y`, so is `y` the package name or is `x` the package name? I thought adding a couple type definitions would be as simple as defining a `.d.ts` file is in typescript, but I'm finding it a bit trickier than that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out the proper way to solve this, so here's a hack instead. I created a file called `rpigpio.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Forward some declarations from the GPIO package so that I can use them. I
couldn't figure out how to get the Python type checking system to work right,
so I just decided to move all the errors here instead
"""
from typing import Callable

from RPi import GPIO


def setup(pin: int, mode: int, pull_up_down: int) -> None:
    return GPIO.setup(pin, mode, pull_up_down=pull_up_down)


def add_event_detect(pin: int, edge: int, callback: Callable, bouncetime: int) -> None:
    return GPIO.add_event_detect(pin, edge, callback=callback, bouncetime=bouncetime)


PUD_UP: int = GPIO.PUD_UP
IN: int = GPIO.IN
FALLING: int = GPIO.FALLING
```

Now in my main code I can remove the `from RPi import GPIO` and replace it with `import rpigpio`. I then replaced all instances of `GPIO` in the code with `rpigpio`. Now all the type errors have been moved to the `rpigpio.py` file so I don't have to look at them.

Yep, it's horrible. If someone else can post an explicit answer of how to do this the right way, I would greatly appreciate it.